Jupyter Kernel Problem - Not using Virtual Environment Kernel
I want to run jupyter notebook using the virtual environment of python. The environment is visible in kernel list of jupyter but when I select it and write commands -
import sys
print(sys.executable)

It still shows the python of main computer not the virtual environment one. Even on seeing the packages list using pip list shows the package of main python not of virtual env. Please help in how to run jupyter notebook using created virtual environment.

creating-and-using-virtual-environment-on-jupyter-notebook-with-python
